# Untar a file on Solaris reports - tar: directory checksum error

Tags: linux, tar

Hi I am trying to untar a compressed file on a Solaris server. I run the command

```
tar xvf 4.56_release.tar.gz
```

But this reports the following error

> tar: directory checksum error

Initially I thought it was a bad download so I re-downloaded the file (actually a different version) and it reports the same error. 
Un-compressing and un-tar'ing it on Linux on a Linux server works fine.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `.tar.gz` is the hint for what you are doing wrong - you are not uncompressing it first. If your version of `tar` supports it, you can use the `-z` flag to specify it is compressed with gzip:

```
tar -xzvf 4.56_release.tar.gz
```

Otherwise, you'll have to `gunzip` it manually:

```
gunzip -c 4.56_release.tar.gz | tar xvf -
```

(The reason it works on Linux is probably that is has a newer/different version which automagically detects the compression)

Comment: Thanks, the version of tar didn't support the -z but using the gunzip resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a '.tar.bz2' type of archive file and neither of the above options worked ('-z' is not supported for your version of 'tar'), you can use:

```
bzip2 -d your_file.tar.bz2
```

to decompress, then use tar:

```
tar -xvf your_file.tar
```

Taken from here: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/solaris-opensolaris-20/how-to-unpack-a-tar-bz2-file-654772/

Answer (score 0):

Solaris tar automatically detects if the tar file is compressed or not, as does Linux. But older versions of Solaris and Linux do not do this.  For Solaris, I think it needs to be Solaris 11 or greater to automatically detect compressed files.  Otherwise use the `tar -z` option.